# Scale text based on browser height and width

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get my text to resize based on the browser size, meaning when the user changes the browser height, the text will get smaller or bigger, also if the user changes the width then the text again gets smaller or bigger.

i've got this bit of jquery but I am very new to this and I don't know how to change it. i've also attached a fiddle here.

http://jsfiddle.net/6FUHp/1/

and here's the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var $body = $('body'); //Cache this for performance

        var setBodyScale = function() {
            var scaleFactor = 0.55,
                scaleSource = $(window).height(),
                maxScale = 600,
                minScale = 10;

            var fontSize = scaleSource * scaleFactor; //Multiply the width of the body by the scaling factor:

            if (fontSize > maxScale) fontSize = maxScale;
            if (fontSize < minScale) fontSize = minScale; //Enforce the minimum and maximums

            $('body').css('font-size', fontSize + '%');
        }

        $(window).resize(function(){
            setBodyScale();
        });

        //Fire it when the page first loads:
        setBodyScale();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've written the text is adjusting fine for when the browser windows height is resized but you hadn't added anything to test the browsers width. Please see this update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6FUHp/2/)

I've amended your line from:

`scaleSource = $(window).height(),`

to

`scaleSource = ($(window).height()/2) + ($(window).width()/2),`

I've assumed your scale but you get the idea.

Comment: That's working perfect, do you know why i can't change the font size though as text 1 and text 2 should be different sizes?

Comment: Yes very simply you had added `font size` instead of `font-size` with the hyphen. Please see the update fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/6FUHp/3/

Comment: And use `em` rather than `px` ... another updated fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/6FUHp/4/